# How to keep NERDTree on the left side

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I start NERDTree every time I fire up vim and keep it that way. However, when I open a window for reference, and move it to the bottom, my NERDTree shrink and the window fills in, like this[image]

How can I make the NERDTree stay on the left side and not shrink?

Comment: Did you try `<C-w>H` in the NERDTree window?

Comment: consider reading this: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/

Comment: Vim's windowing system is poorly usable and designed, you'd have to write a macro to reposition nerdtree on the left, or toggle it, to make Vim behave like any modern editor that always keeps a file browser on the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd><kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd></kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> will do that for you. There are more combinations that will help you with similar things in this similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4571319

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not exactly what you want. First of all you should consider to open the second file by pressing `i` while you are in the NERDTree. Then you don't have to move your window to the bottom because it splits your window on the right. Secondly you may want to have a look at [this vim plugin](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs). Even this one won't solve your problem but ensures a more IDE like behavior with showing a NERDTree on all tabs on the left side.