# vim send window to the right (not move the cursor)

Tags: vim

I want to have a 4 grid layout in vim. I am using the NERDTree to open multiple files. Whenever I use "s" or "i", files are open in my first column (I have two columns).

Please see picture:

[image]

How can I move one file to the right? So that I have the 4 grid layout that I want.

I've tried this:

[Vim: Move window left/right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556184/vim-move-window-left-right)

But this is for moving yourself between windows (or buffers I think they are called)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've not used nerd tree so this information might be entirely useless, but normally when opening new viewports (the 'files', which are actually buffers in viewports), the location they open in is based on which viewport your cursor is in. Try putting your cursor in a different viewport using `ctrl+w+h/j/k/l` before opening another file.

If this is entirely unhelpful let me know and I'll nuke the comment.

Comment: yeah, the problem is that I am in the second column, when I typed :NERDTree, the cursor dissapears from this file in the column and goes to the NERDTree. So when I open the file with "s" or "i", it is always added in the first column by default.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I can't offer you anything but roundabout hacks. I've decided to leave the comment up for future readers.